# Completing a commutative diagram

Tags: category-theory

Suppose we have an square in an abelian category $\mathcal C$:

$$\begin{matrix} A & & B \\
                 f \downarrow & & g \downarrow\\
                C & \rightarrow & D \end{matrix} $$

Where $f : A\rightarrow C$ has trivial cokernel and $g : B\rightarrow D$ has trivial kernel.

In my particular case, the map from $C$ to $D$ is also an isomorphism, but I'm wondering what happens if it isn't.

What conditions do we need for there to exist an arrow $A\rightarrow B$ that makes the square commutative?

I've seen in some literature that this arrow exists, but I've never seen any explanation as to why or how this arrow exists, and I don't see any reason for it to necessarily exist.

Comment: What conditions are sufficient to guarantee the existence of the arrow?

Comment: Yeah I've asked it in far too much generality in hindsight. I will edit the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f,g$ be as in the diagram in the question and let $f$ be an epimorphism and $g$ a monomorphism (equivalent to $f$ has trivial cokernel and $g$ has trivial kernel).
Let us consider the case when $h \colon C \to D$ is an epimorphism, which holds in your more particular case. Then the composition  $A \overset{f}{\to} C \overset{h}{\to} D$  is an epimorphism, and thus the composition  $A \to B \overset{g}{\to} D$  would have to be an epimorphism. Then $g$ would have to be an epimorphism, and hence an isomorphism. 
So in this case there is such a map  $A \to B$  if and only if $g$ is an isomorphism.

If the map  $h \colon C \to D$  is arbitrary I am not much help. 
You can say such a map $A \to B$ exists if and only if the composition $\mathrm{Cok}(g) \circ h \circ f = 0$, but that is really just saying the same thing with different words, using that $g$, being a monomorphism, is the kernel of its cokernel.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose such an $j:A\to B$ exists, and denote $h: C\to D$ the bottom map. Then $f$ factors through the pullback of $g$ along $h$, wich is a mono because $g$ is, and an epi because $f$ is, hence an iso: $C\times_D B\simeq C$. In particular there is a projection $p: C \to B$ such that $gp=h$.

Conversely, if there is $p: C \to B$ such that $gp=h$, of course $j = pf$ makes the diagram commute. (In that case, even if not relevant, $C$ is again the pullback $C\times_D B$ beacause $g$ is mono.)

In the end, the square can be completed if and only if there is $p: C\to B$ such that $gp=h$.

---

Some intuition (I'm not skilled enough in abelian categories to say how formal this can be made): as $g$ is mono, you can think of the pullback $C\times_D B$ as the graph of $h$ restricted to those elements in $C$ whose image in $B$. Hence, saying that this restricted graph is iso to $C$ is saying that the image of $C$ is actually in $B$.

---

**Remark**. I don't really use the "abelianness" of the category here, just that epi+mono=iso and existence of pullbacks.

Comment: A category where epi+mono=iso is called a [balanced category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/balanced+category).